# WATIR - How can I locate an element using more than one identifier

Tags: watir

My test is trying to check whether or not an error message or a success message is displayed.

The CSS for the two messages is:

```
span id="APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE" data-template-id="20696621797766286675_S" class="apex-page-success u-hidden"


span id="APEX_ERROR_MESSAGE" data-template-id="20696621797766286675_E" class="apex-page-success u-hidden"
```

I've tried using id to locate them (if browser.span(:id=> "APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE").exists?) but the trouble is that it treats both the error and the success message as the same thing by just using id. I'm guessing I need to locate them using the data-template-id="20696621797766286675_S" but I don't know how to implement that into my code without getting an error.

Any ideas?[CSS for the messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cblob.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given each `span` has a unique id, I would expect only 1 element to be located. I wouldn't expect to need a second identifier.

I would guess that the problem is how the element is being used, specifically the usage of `#exists?`. `#exists?` verifies that the element appears in the HTML. It does not verify whether or not the element is actually visible to the user.

Given the markup screenshot, it looks like both elements are likely always included in the HTML, however they are hidden or shown the user by toggling the "u-hidden" class. What I think you actually want is to use `#present?`, which checks if the element is actually visible to the user:

```
if browser.span(:id=> "APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE").present?
```

To answer, your question about using multiple identifiers, the identifier is a `Hash`. You can add additional items. Note that for data-* attributes, they need the dash replaced by underscores:

```
browser.span(id: "APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE", data_template_id "20696621797766286675_S")
```

Comment: Looks like `u-hidden` class is added when the element is not active. If you're looking for this to work with just a locator, you might try: `browser.span(id: "APEX_SUCCESS_MESSAGE", class: ["!u-hidden"])`

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks both. I was able to combine both your solutions and get this to work.

Comment: @bobbie_j If he answers your question, please accept the answer by clicking the hallow tic on the left top corner, on your click it will turn into green colour.